# failed login to ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: boot, login, grubrescue

I can't log into Ubuntu 12.04.4  on my laptop, it goes into (ash) without finding the root directory. I tried to log in with ctrl+alt+F6 but get a blank screen.
I have a Ubuntu 12,04.3 disk but am not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Exit to console after you boot, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, and login with your username and password. Once you are there you can install MDM as default login greeter for Ubuntu. Code is:

```
 sudo apt-get install mdm
```

Choose MDM as your default when prompted, and there you go. You can customize the login greeter so you can login as root or as user, and you can also disable potentially dangerous hosts with MDM. It should work, and LighDM will still be present as your display manager.

If you want to uninstall MDM for various reasons you need to type this code:

```
 sudo apt-get remove mdm
```

And choose lightdm greeter as default when prompted.

You can also change the password for root like this:
    sudo passwd

And choose a new password for root, and after that try to login as root. If it works it is ok but you shoudl not perform any operations when logged in as root.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ctrl+alt+F6 as recommended but it failed as well as ctrl+alt+F1 but it just left a blank screen. After some further investigation it looked like it wasn't seeing the partition properly (file system not recognised) so with my installation dick in the Try Ubuntu mode and an Ethernet link to my router I got the Boot-Repair instructions from the Ubuntu Community Wiki site and following the instructions it restored the system, I still don't know the cause of the failure though.
John